# Swift (Xcode 6.1 beta 2) Core Data on OS X with XML store—NSSortDescriptor doesn’t find key

Tags: xml, macos, core-data, swift, nssortdescriptor

I’m working on learning Core Data while also working on internalizing Swift. I’m using Nick Smith’s “Xcode Primer—Starting Core Data”, and doing each exercise first in Objective-C, as in the book, and then in Swift. Right now, I’m using Xcode 6.1 beta 2 on Mavericks 10.9.5, and, at the moment, I’m on Chapter 5 of the book, which is worked on OS X, and therefore defaults to XML store. The Objective-C version is fine, all the way through, but in Swift, I fail when I get to the sub-chapter on sorting, with

```
[<NSXMLDocumentMapNode ...> valueForUndefinedKey:]: this class is not 
key value coding-compliant for the key price.
```

(“price” is the correct name of the attribute being sorted on.)

I’ve gone so far as to delete and retype the entire project several times; whatever the problem is, it’s not a simple typo. I know that the class has to be changed from *entity-name* to *project-name*.*entity-name*, and if that’s not done right, the project will fail at an earlier stage, so I know it’s not that. All my classes are tagged @objc, so it’s not that.

Answer (score 0):

Breakthrough! I found the fix as a side-effect of fixing another superficially mad error. I had to change the code from:

```
let sort2 = NSSortDescriptor(key: "price", ascending: true)
```

to:

```
let sort2 = NSSortDescriptor(key: "price" as NSString, ascending: true)
```

On to the next chapter!